# How to set a fixed window size using Perl Tkx

Tags: perl

I am trying to create a GUI window using perl.
But the created GUI window size differs in different system.

**Could anyone please tell me, how to set the fixed size, so that, it won't change depends on the following factors,

 - Any resolution we set in our desktop

 - Any system we use

 - Any OS we use**

Code Snippet i used in Perl:

```
use Tkx;
my $MainWindow = Tkx::widget -> new(".");
$MainWindow -> g_wm_geometry("600x15+340+612");

$MainFrame = $MainWindow -> new_ttk__frame();
$ExtractionTypeLabel = $MainFrame -> new_ttk__label(-text => &lt;&lt;TEXT&gt;&gt;,
-padding => 10,
);
$ExtractionTypeSingle = $MainFrame -> new_ttk__radiobutton(-text =>$ConfMainSingleExtractionText,
-variable => \$ExtractionTypeVal,
-value => $ConfMainSingleExtractionText,
-command => \&SINGLE_RADIO_BUTTON_LISTENER,
);
##### ALIGNMENT IN GRID LAYOUT #####
$ExtractionTypeLabel -> g_grid(-row => 3, -column => 0, -pady => 1);
$ExtractionTypeSingle -> g_grid(-row => 4, -column => 0, -ipadx => 4);
##### PACK #####
$MainFrame -> g_pack(-in => $MainWindow);
Tkx::MainLoop();
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to set a particular window size.

$MainWindow ->configure( -width=> 100, -height=> 100 );